# how to send data to another page without exciting current page php

Tags: php, html, ajax

so I am having a page where there is an input field. I want this to work like a CMS system. Let's say that there are options. What I am working on now is one where you can specify how long the summery will be for the content. So I want the input to be saved and sent to the function file where I can use that information in a function. I don't want to be sent to this function file site.
Similar to how you can save options in wordpress, but you stay on the same page.
I imagine that I perhaps have to use AJAX.

Any help on how I can do this?

Comment: AJAX is the way to go if you want to see your changes in the page without refreshing in browser.

Comment: Daniel in Stackoverflow some code is required for suggestions , some research work is required

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use some JavaScript here, then localStorage could be of great help to you.

Suppose you have following html form:

```
<input id = "foo" type = "text">
```

Write this JavaScript to store the value:

```
var val = foo.value;
localStorage.setItem(formV,val);
```

And the following to retrieve it:

```
val = localStorage.getItem(formV);
```

You can then make an AJAX request to transfer the data to a PHP file:

```
request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'form.php',
        data: { text1: val}});
        
        request.done( function(response) {
        
    alert("cool!");
        })
```

On form.php side:

```
$val = $_POST['text1'];
 echo $val;
```

You can learn more about localStorage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and many other places.

Comment: thanks a lot! this looks very useful! I am going to test this when I get home. I will check your answer as helped if I can get it to work c:

Comment: I cannot get this to work. First of all a form tag cannot have a type, but the input field inside it does. So I tried it with just adding that id and type to an input within the form, but it still doesn't work at all.